# Using Class Methods and Instances Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I am trying to challenge myself by taking on this small project. I have 2 tables I am trying to generate a list from. My view has 2 drop downs,one of all Users emails and The Seconds dropdown has a list of all the Weeks Start Dates... I need to generate a list of all the Weeks that have the params of the User.email, Week.start date and Week.status of approved...

I don't believe I am doing this right, and I haven't worked on something like this before so please don't destroy me here...

This is my model

```
      def self.approved_week(start_date,email)
        logger.debug(" LOOK LOOK ")
        user = User.where(:email => params[:email])
        start_date = Week.where(:start_date => params[:start_date])
        approved_week = Week.where(:status_id => 3)  
       end
```

Controller

```
    #Choose Approved Timesheet to Reset
      def reset
        logger.debug("YOU ARE WATCHING: #{params.inspect}")
        @user = User.all
       @weeks = Week.all
        logger.debug("USER EMAIL: #{params[:email]}")
        logger.debug "USER START DATE #{params[:start_date]}"
        call approved_week here how???
     end
```

or should I do define my week as Week.where(:status_id => 3, :start_date =>(params[:start_date])

. I am lost here trying to generate a view the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :)
Yes - you should define the weeks using all the required criteria at once.

```
user = User.where(:email => params[:email])
start_date = Week.where(:start_date => params[:start_date])
approved_week = Week.where(:status_id => 3)
```

This has two sets of weeks and you could in theory fetch out the weeks that are in both sets... but it's much slower to do that in ruby than it is to do it in a single query eg as you say:

```
Week.where(:status_id => 3, :start_date => params[:start_date])
```

The rails way to do this would be to create a couple of scopes on `Week`, into which you can pass the relevant details cand then chain together in the controller

Here is how you might define the scopes:

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_APPROVED = 3
  ...
  scope :approved, ->() { where(:status_id => STATUS_APPROVED) }
  scope :starting_on, -> (start_date) { where(:start_date => start_date) }
```

Then you can use these in the controller like this:

```
  def reset
    logger.debug("YOU ARE WATCHING: #{params.inspect}")
    @user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).last
    @weeks = Week.approved.starting_on(params[:start_date]).all
 end
```

Comment: I think you meant  `Week.approved.starting_on(.....`. You don't need the start_date in the approved scope, neither `.all` in @weeks.